# How to update one table using another table in CakePHP 3

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.x

I have two tables like *status_report* and *holiday*. I want to update *status_report* table using *holiday* table. I want to generate below SQL using CakePHP.

```
UPDATE AttendanceReports s, holiday h
SET s.Status = h.description
WHERE s.work_date =  h.work_date and
      h.work_date between '2015-05-05' and '2015-12-31';
```

**How to write this query in CakePHP?** (I'm using CakePHP 3.x)

I have tried the following but I don't know how to set status field using another table's date.

```
$this->loadModel('Usermgmt.AttendanceReports');
$dateStart = date('Y-m-01') ;
$dateEnd = date('Y-m-t');
$q = $this->AttendanceReports->query()
     ->update('AttendanceReports s, Holidays h')
     ->set(['s.status = h.description'])
     ->where(['s.work_date =  h.work_date','h.work_date BETWEEN :start AND :end'])
     ->bind(':start', $dateStart)
     ->bind(':end', $dateEnd)
     ->execute();
```

this will generate right output like this

```
UPDATE AttendanceReports s, Holidays h 
SET s.status = h.description 
WHERE (s.work_date = h.work_date AND 
       h.work_date BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-01-31')
```

But it gives error like below:

> **Error:** SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'ollo_hrm.attendancereports' doesn't exist

[image: Screenshot of the error message]

Comment: $offday = $this->loadModel('StatusReports');
        $dateStart='';
        $dateStart ='';
        $query_offday = $offday->query();
        $query_offday->update()
            ->set(['status' => $status])
            ->where(['work_date BETWEEN :start AND :end'])
            ->bind(':start', $dateStart)
            ->bind(':end', $dateStart)
            ->execute(); i am trying this one but i dont know how to set status field using another table data.

Comment: Please add the php code to your question by editing it.

Comment: do you actually have a table named AttendanceReports? Or it is attendance_reports

Comment: yeah table name is attendance_reports. now its working. Thank you so much @arilia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't try the code at the moment but something like this should work

```
$q = $this->StatusReports->query()
    ->update('status_report s, holiday h')
    ->set(['s.Status = h.Ocassion'])
    ->where(function ($exp, $q) {
            return $exp->add('s.Workdate =  h.holiday_date')
            ->between('h.holiday_date','2015-05-05', '2015-12-31');
        }
    );
```

Comment: its not working . I have tried the following but it gives error.code like below $this->loadModel('Usermgmt.AttendanceReports');
    $dateStart = date('Y-m-01') ;
    $dateEnd = date('Y-m-t');
    $q = $this->AttendanceReports->query()
        ->update('AttendanceReports s, Holidays h')
        ->set(['s.status = h.description'])
        ->where(['s.work_date =  h.work_date','h.work_date BETWEEN :start AND :end'])
        ->bind(':start', $dateStart)
        ->bind(':end', $dateEnd)
        ->execute();